# Set the size of the plot, Plotly React

Tags: reactjs, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly.js, plotly-react

Is it possible to set the width of the graph and the width of the legend separately?

Because "width" in the layout set the width for all plot.

I want to have the next behavior, graph always has the 80% of width and legend the rest 20%.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Plotly layout docs](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout) give many different options for customizing the layout of your graph.

```js
// entrywidth is a fraction, so 0.2 would be 20%. entrywidthmode specifies that entrywidth is a fraction, not pixels.
layout={{width: 320, height: 240, legend: {entrywidth: 0.2, entrywidthmode: "fraction"}}}
```

Comment: I was thinking this would work too, but I tried it out and it doesn't seem to work. Did you test this?

Comment: it doesn't work, the layout doesn't have such attributes as  entrywidth and entrywidthmode

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helps me for now, is to add x value for the legend:

```
 legend: {
          x: 1.3,
          xanchor: "right"
    }
```